# Configuring Winston Logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, logging, winston

I'm building a Node.js application and can't figure out how to configure the winston logger the right way.

**What I would like to acchieve:**

- My application should have 6 custom logging levels (fatal, error, warning, status, info & debug). For those levels, there should be methods such as logger.status(message, ...details).
- I would like to be able to pass additional JS objects (details) after the message for debugging/evaluation purposes.
- Logs should be printed to the console

  - All console outputs should look the following:
    `[ISO Date String] [Level in uppercase]: [Log Message]`
  - fatal & error logs should be printed in red
  - debug & info logs should only be printed if a constant (e.g. this.debug related to my class) is set to true. debug logs should be printed in yellow.
- Logs of all levels should be written to a DailyRotateFile, in the same format as above (except for the colors of course).
- Logs should be stored in a MongoDB with the following properties: date, level, message, details (containing all objects passed), label (specifies from which part of the log was sent, to be set manually).

**What I've done so far:**

As recommended, I've extended the default winston class using TypeScript in order to add methods for my specific logging levels:

```
import winston = require('winston');

interface Logger extends winston.Logger {
    fatal: winston.LeveledLogMethod;
    error: winston.LeveledLogMethod;
    warning: winston.LeveledLogMethod;
    status: winston.LeveledLogMethod;
    info: winston.LeveledLogMethod;
    debug: winston.LeveledLogMethod;
}
```

From this interface, I've created an instance like so:

```
this.logger = <Logger>winston.createLogger({
    levels: {
        fatal: 0,
        error: 1,
        warning: 2,
        status: 3,
        info: 4,
        debug: 5
    },
    level: 'debug',
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({

        }),
        new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
            filename: 'cplus-%DATE%.log',
            dirname: this.logsDir,
            datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm'
        }),
        new winston.transports.MongoDB({
            db: this.dbClient
        })
    ]
});
```

Basic logging to the console & file using the new methods works fine, for example

`this.logger.fatal('Connection to database ' + this.dbUrl + ' failed, cannot start', err);`

creates the following output:

`{"message":"Connection to database mongodb://localhost:27017 failed, cannot startAuthentication failed.","name":"MongooseServerSelectionError","reason": ...`

Now, how do I acchieve the rest, such as formatting and correct storing in MongoDB? I've tried a few different things using the preset Winston formats, with no success.

Best regards!

Comment: Hi @Fabian Stern have you found the solution for this. I am looking for configuring the winston3 using yml/json configurations.